# Unable to get data of forecast hourly in openweathermap

Tags: react-native, openweathermap, weather-api

I am tried to fetch data of current weather data it was successful but if I try to fetch data of forecast hourly it showing 401 error

```
fetch(`https://pro.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?q=${cityname}&appid=${API_KEY}`,)
  .then(res => res.json().then(res => console.log(res)),);
```

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. So either your apikey is invalid or you are using it wrong. And what about those extra commas?